# search a text in a svn repository across all releases

Tags: full-text-search

I need to search a text in a SVN repository, inside all revisions.
I am trying this software, which indexes all repositories and then you can search:

http://www.supose.org/projects/supose/wiki

```
#create the index
./bin/supose  sc -U "svn://..." --username ... -p ... --fromrev 0 --create

#search
./bin/supose  se -Q "+contents:class"
```

if i understood correctly, this should search across all files for the text "class".
this should return a lot of matches, as there a lot of java files.
however, it only returns maches in some .xml; it is ignoring java files.
why?

and what is the "search --fields" option? what is a field?

Comment: For some reason the `+contents` index is not populated for Java files -- I'm not sure if that is a bug or a design feature.  However, if you disable `com.soebes.supose.core.scan.document.ScanJavaDocument` in `etc/fileextension.properties`, `+contents` queries work as expected