# how to find local svn repositories?

Tags: svn

Over the years, I have created several repositories on one computer. How do I find for all local svn repositories?

I do have a solution but want to know if you know anything better:

```
  find ~/ -name rep-cache.db
```

But the problem is that this solution does not tell me when the repo was last updated. I am not asking for how to search within a repository, [which has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254214/svn-repository-search) or for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855228/search-a-text-in-a-svn-repository-across-all-releases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the last update you could use any of the below

1. svnlook date to find the last commit date

   ```
   find ~/ \
       -type d -name db \
       -print \
       -exec sh -c 'svnlook date $(dirname {})' \;
   ```

   This would print error message if it finds a directory named `db` which is not a svn repo.
2. ls -l, if you are interested only in the last modified date

   ```
   find ~/ \
       -name rep-cache.db \
       -print \
       -exec ls -l {} \;
   ```

Comment: The second one was better